# ODBC package is not getting loaded in R

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, odbc

I'm trying to connect R with Snowflake.

I tried to test the connection with the below code

```r
install.packages("DBI")
install.packages("ODBC")
library(DBI)
library(ODBC)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(
                      odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver = 'snowflakeDSIIDriver', 
                      Server = 'xxxxx.snowflakecomputing.com',
                      UID = 'abcdef', 
                      PWD='123456',
                      DATABASE = 'Production')
```

When I execute the code, I'm getting the below error

```
error in evaluating the argument 'drv' in selecting a method for function 'dbConnect': there is no package called ‘odbc’
```

It seems like ODBC is not getting read in here even after installing it. I'm using R 4.0.5 version.

Any help would be appreciated to solve the error

Comment: should ODBC be all lower case like this install.packages("odbc")

Comment: Package and function names in R are case sensitive. You should have also gotten error on `install.packages("ODBC")` warning you about the typo and `library(ODBC)` before even running the `dbConnect` command.

Comment: You should pay closer attention to the warnings and errors emitted when you try commands. Namely, when running the code block above, your _second line of code_ is going to warn `Warning: package 'ODBC' is not available for this version of R`, which means that the package you wanted to install was not found and therefore was not installed. (In my opinion that should be an `Error:`, not a warning.) Regardless, on your fourth line of code, `library(ODBC)` should have ***erred*** with `Error in library(ODBC) : there is no package called 'ODBC'`, clear indication. Don't ignore errors/warnings.

Comment: I made all lowercase for install.packages("odbc"). When I ran the library(odbc) command I got the error as follows
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘odbc’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versioncheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘hms’

Comment: Works fine for me the code on R 4.2.2. The `odbc` lib is indeed small caps, but for the rest I used exactly same code and it works fine.

Comment: I installed the odbc package by defining the type and it worked. install.packages("odbc", type="binary")